# OnSelChanged fires only once

Tags: c++, mfc

So if i'm selecting an item, OnSelChanged it's called, but after, if i'm selecting the **same** item the OnSelChanged isn't called again. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Which control? Is the item unselected first? You cannot select something that is already selected.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to fit the function name. On Selection *Changed*. If you select the same item again, nothing changed and the function won't get called. What you describe is the expected behavior.

Comment: I had a couple of tables and on some of them the OnSelChanged was called even though the item was already selected, but this behavior wasn't on all of them. I solved the problem setting the behavior of the tr of table 'clickable' to redirect the calling to OnBtnClicked. Thank you for your hint Remy and nvoigt.

Comment: @Zack: Now you have a GUI that behaves differently when operated with a mouse and a keyboard.